# Is it OK to rename the folder associated with a Microsoft Form that has File Upload fields?

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-forms

When you add fields of type `File Upload` to a Microsoft Teams group owned Microsoft Form, a folder is created at:

`Documents` > `Apps` > `Microsoft Forms` > `Your Form Name`

That folder is where the uploaded files are saved.

I had a Microsoft Teams group owned Microsoft Form.

I copied the form, and then renamed the copy of the form.

The folder name of the copied form, however, located at `Documents` > `Apps` > `Microsoft Forms`, is still:

```
My Original Form Name 1
```

So the folders in `Documents` > `Apps` > `Microsoft Forms` are currently:

```
My Original Form Name
My Original Form Name 1
```

Can those folders be renamed or will it break connections between the form and where the files are being saved (or anything else)?

To clarify, I want to rename both of the folders so the contents of `Documents` > `Apps` > `Microsoft Forms` is:

```
My Original Form Renamed
My New Form Name
```

**Edit:**

*Additionally*, I've just realised the names of the sub folders within the form folders (that relate to a specific file upload field) do not change when you change the field name.

Or rather, sometimes they do and sometimes they don't.

So I have a weird looking bunch of folders - can those sub folders be renamed?

This is what I currently have:

```
Actual Field Name
Question
Question 1
Another Field Name
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question but was unable to find an answer so I tested it out with my own form (which already had responses with attachments submitted).

RESULT - Yes! You can rename the folders.  New form submissions continue to drop attachments into the correct, existing folders.

To ensure you rename the correct folders to match the correct questions:

1. In the Form, click the "Responses" tab
2. Navigate to the attachments question
3. Click "More Details"
4. Click "View in folder" (this will open a new tab to the source folder location)
5. Rename the selected folder in Sharepoint to match your Form question